# Cookies behavior in `<script>` tag, and fetch inside a `.server.ts` file in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I attempting to create a SvelteKit application, and I think I am misunderstanding the use of `fetch` and `hooks`. When I have a login page, and in the form actions I am able to decode a `jwt` and add it to the cookies, however, it seems that if I make a request from inside of a `<script>` tag that those cookies are not a part of the request, meaning that I am not authenticated to my rest framework backend when I use `fetch()` inside of a `<script>` After reading the SvelteKit docs, and about "not importing sensitive information" into the frontend client, I am having difficulty understanding these things:

1. If it is possible to have a fetch in the frontend that passes a token from cookies to headers somehow and also
2. Is this the intended use for fetch in SvelteKit?
3. What is the use for hooks.server.ts?
4. Am I setting cookies correctly?

`src/routes/+page.server.ts`

```js
import { type Actions, type ServerLoad } from "@sveltejs/kit";


export const load: ServerLoad = async ({ locals, fetch, request }) => {
    const url = new URL(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}chronique/records/get_descriptions/`);
    if (params) { url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString(); }
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'GET' });
    return {
        user: locals.user as User,
    }
};
```

`src/routes/login/+page.server.ts` - login form action

```js
export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ cookies, request, locals}) => {
        await logout(cookies);
        const data = await request.formData() as FormData;
        const username = data.get('username');
        const password = data.get('password');
        let response = await login(username, password) as Response;
        let json = await response.json() as TokenResponse;

        if (!response || response.status == 401) { 
            return fail(400, { failure: true });
        }

        let secure = import.meta.env.PROD ? true : false;
        const decoded = await jwt.verify(json.access, import.meta.env.VITE_SECRET_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'), {
            algorithms: ['RS256'],
        }) as jwt.VerifyOptions as JWTPayload;
        console.log('cookies set');
        cookies.set('user_id', decoded.user_id, { path: '/', secure: secure, httpOnly: !secure, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 });
        cookies.set('access', json.access, { path: '/', secure: secure, httpOnly: !secure, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 });
        cookies.set('refresh', json.refresh, { path: '/', secure: secure, httpOnly: !secure, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 });
;       
        // get user
        const api_response = await getUser({ access_token: json.access, user_id: decoded.user_id }) as Response | undefined;
        const response_json = await api_response.json() as UserApiResponse;
        let user = {
            id: decoded.user_id,
            username: response_json.username,
            email: response_json.email,
        } as User;

        locals.user = user;

        throw redirect(302, '/app');
    },
} satisfies Actions;
```

`src/hooks.server.ts`

```js
import type { Handle, HandleFetch } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const user_id = event.cookies.get('user_id') as string | undefined;
    const access_token = event.cookies.get('access') as string | undefined;
    const user = event.locals.user as User | undefined;
    console.log('user', user);
    if (access_token) console.log('has access token in handle');
    if (user_id) console.log('has user id in handle');
    if (!access_token) {
        if (event.url.pathname !== '/login') {
            await logout(event.cookies);
        }
        return resolve(event);
    }
    return resolve(event);
};

export const handleFetch: HandleFetch = async ({ event, request, fetch }) => {
    console.log('hooks - handleFetch')
    const access_token = event.cookies.get('access') as string | undefined;
    if (access_token) { console.log('has access token'); }
    else { console.log('no access token'); }
    if (access_token) {
        request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
    }

    return await fetch(request);
};
```

When I login, I can see from my console log in hooks that the access token makes it back to the hooks after logging in, however, when my `src/routes/+page.svelte` loads, and calls the `ServerLoad`, I can see from my log statements there are no cookies or access tokens available in getFetch.

My goal is to use fetch within a script tag, and not have to apply the cookies where the fetch is made from the script tag, but have them set in the request headers somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you can do is using locals to set values of access_token, user_id and refresh before the last return resolve(event) :

```
import type { Handle, HandleFetch } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const user_id = event.cookies.get('user_id') as string | undefined;
    const access_token = event.cookies.get('access') as string | undefined;
    const user = event.locals.user as User | undefined;
    console.log('user', user);
    if (access_token) console.log('has access token in handle');
    if (user_id) console.log('has user id in handle');
    if (!access_token) {
        if (event.url.pathname !== '/login') {
            await logout(event.cookies);
        }
        return resolve(event);
    }

    event.locals.access_token = access_token
    event.locals.user_id = user_id
    return resolve(event);
};

export const handleFetch: HandleFetch = async ({ event, request, fetch }) => {
    console.log('hooks - handleFetch')
    // instead of getting them from cookie, retrieve them from locals
    // before : const access_token = event.cookies.get('access') as string | undefined;
    // after
    access_token = event.locals.access_token
    if (access_token) { console.log('has access token'); }
    else { console.log('no access token'); }
    if (access_token) {
        request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
    }

    return await fetch(request);
};
```